# java home will not set using /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables

wowee.......

```
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/' | tee -a /etc/environment
```

open up new terminal

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
blank
```

Why is it sooo hard to set a global env for all users without restarting?  eve  tried source

OK..I get placing env vars in users .bashrc and using source but why I cant to the same for /etc/environment?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/environment` is not read by the shell but by the `pam_env` PAM module.

So it is only evaluated at login time and you can't use shell syntax but only

```
VARIABLE=VALUE
```

lines.

Use

```
echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

and login again.

Comment: @Tampa: A useful page on the topic is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables